# Install and use sass on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sass

After installing Sass on Ubuntu like:

```
$ sudo gem install sass
$ sass -v
  Sass 3.2.11 (Media Mark)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sass --watch tst.sass
```

**NameError: uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin::StalenessChecker::Mutex
  Use --trace for backtrace.**

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

just type in terminal

```
sass --watch .
```

where **.** is your current folder

Comment: Did you mentioned the NameError?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`sass --watch tst.sass:../css/tst.css`

You need to give it a output filename as well. You can change ../css above to wherever you want your CSS file to appear